# I want that my string that i enter maunaly displays numbers of repeted character "ma" but i am stuck i am new to C

Tags: c, string

I am new to C programming and I want to display how many times did "ma" showed up for example "mamama" there is 3 "ma" but in my code when I write "mamam" it displays 3 "ma". Sorry for my bad explanation... I recently started studying C programming.

I tried with do-while  but I end up screwing even more..

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char a[81];
   int i, j;
   int zbroj=0;
   i=0;

   fgets(a,81,stdin);

   for(i=0; i<'m';i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j<'a';j++)
       {
            while(a[i] !='\0')
            {
       if(a[i] == 'm' || a[j]=='a')
       {
           zbroj++;
       }    
       i++; 
   }
       }
   }

   printf("%d\n", zbroj);

    return 0;
}
```

Well, the end goal is when I type "mamam" program should write down there is 2 "ma".

Comment: Those two loops `for(i=0; i<'m';i++)` and `for(j=0; j<'a';j++)` are very strange, and not what you want.  I suspect you want `i` to iterate over the number of characters in the string.  (Here you've got it making a constant 109 trips, which doesn't make sense.)  I'm not sure you need the second, `j` loop at all, but if you do, you probably want to make 2 trips (the number of characters in "ma"), not 106.

Comment: You only need one loop for this problem.You iterate through char array and when you have a 'm' you check if the next is 'a'.I can't understand your code completely. Sometimes you must first think simple and create a program for the general problem and after consider the edge cases,which i believe you did here.

Comment: @SteveSummit oke, so should I replace them with a length of my string in this case 81?

Comment: @pandygiankoulidis my task is to allow the user to enter a single string of up to 80 characters. Find and print how many times the "ma" style appears on the screen.

Comment: You can still do it using only one loop.Someone posted how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
int main()
{
   char a[81];
   int i, j;
   int zbroj=0;
   i=0;

   fgets(a,81,stdin);

    while(a[i] !='\0') {
       if(a[i] == 'm' && a[i+1]=='a')
       {
           zbroj++;
           i++;
       }   
       i++;
    };

   printf("%d\n", zbroj);

    return 0;
}
```

Your first iteration are not needed. You need to iterate though the string and check if you have found the letter you want and then check the next one. Then increase the counter. Try to understand what is that each line of code does though. You will need it.

**hint** I have also changed || to &&

Comment: Thanks! So I just needed one for loop.